# Flutter: update LayerLink of OverlayEntry attached to MouseRegion. Problem with Tooltip's Position

Tags: flutter, timer, overlay

I have a ListView.builder with ListTiles wrapped in MouseRegion. When entering a MouseRegion with the mouse an Overlay attached to this MouseRegion shall be shown in the upper right corner of this MouseRegion. Only one Overlay shall be shown simultaneously, and always the one attached to the MouseRegion which is hovered. Since the Overlay contains clickable IconButtons, the Overlay shall still be shown, when exiting the MouseRegion via the Overlay.

The following minimal version (which you can copypaste and run) is doing the job, except for the Tooltips of the IconButtons not updating their positions when moving the mouse quickly.

Any ideas of how to solve this problem?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<SelectedListTileProvider>(
    child: const MyApp(),
    create: (_) => SelectedListTileProvider(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  OverlayEntry? entry;
  Timer? hideTimer;
  bool overlayIsActive = false;
  OverlayState? overlay;

  OverlayEntry buildOverlayEntry() {
    print('buildOverlayEntry');

    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        right: 1,
        child: CompositedTransformFollower(
          link: context.watch<SelectedListTileProvider>().layerLink!,
          showWhenUnlinked: false,
          offset: const Offset(0, -20),
          followerAnchor: Alignment.topRight,
          targetAnchor: Alignment.topRight,
          child: buildOverlay(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showOverlay() {
    print('showOverlay');
    overlay = Overlay.of(context);
    entry = buildOverlayEntry();
    overlay!.insert(entry!);
    overlayIsActive = true;
  }

  void hideOverlay() {
    print('hideOverlay');
    entry?.remove();
    entry = null;
    overlayIsActive = false;
  }

  void enterListTile() {
    print('enterListTile');
    if (!overlayIsActive) {
      showOverlay();
    } else {
      hideTimer!.cancel();
    }
  }

  void exitListTile() {
    print('exitListTile');
    hideTimer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), hideOverlay);
  }

  Widget? buildOverlay() {
    print('build Overlay');
    return MouseRegion(
      onEnter: (e) {
        print('onEnterOverlay');
        hideTimer?.cancel();
      },
      onExit: (e) {
        print('onExitOverlay');
        hideTimer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), hideOverlay);
      },
      child: Material(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              tooltip: 'delete message',
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {},
              tooltip: 'edit message (in progress)',
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_rounded),
              onPressed: () {},
              tooltip: 'start thread (in progress)',
            ),
            IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions), onPressed: () {}, tooltip: 'in progress'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MinimalListTile'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          LayerLink layerLink = LayerLink();
          return CompositedTransformTarget(
            link: layerLink,
            child: MouseRegion(
              onEnter: (e) {
                print('onEnter');
                context.read<SelectedListTileProvider>().layerLink = layerLink;
                enterListTile();
              },
              onExit: (e) {
                print('onExit');
                exitListTile();
              },
              child: ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                title: Text("List item $index"),
                onTap: () {
                  // TODO: implement for Mobile-Platform (easy)
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SelectedListTileProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  LayerLink? _layerLink;
  LayerLink? get layerLink => _layerLink;
  set layerLink(LayerLink? value) {
    _layerLink = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Markus, If your question is about requesting a code review, there's another site for especially doing code reviews on working code. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zerocukor287 Until the "_Problem with the tooltips of the IconButtons..._" is fixed the code would not be [on-topic for CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). BTW I've voted to close this as **Needs more focus**.

Comment: Thanks for your instructions. I removed the request for code review and hopefully set more focus on my problem.